# Passing an email as login to JMeter HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter

Trying to create a JMeter test to login to a site where my username is my email.  I've tried with encode checked and unchecked but it keeps coming back saying invalid login, and in the HTTP request i see it posting the variable with %40 instead of the @ symbol.  Any suggestions on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I see 3 possibilities to pass email as login. I would recommend you to act in the following way(-s): 
**1) name login/password as variables and then pass them in POST login request as parameters:**
[image: parameter initialization]
[image: configuring HTTP request defaults sampler]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**2) to load login (as email)  from .csv file and the pass it in POST request**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**3) to write  [jMeter script using Chrome extension](http://blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeters-chrome-extension-record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter) without launching jMeter.**

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check how the browser is sending your request (encoded or unencoded), you can use a recording with jmeter for that or you can use for example Fiddler.

Step 2: Base your input for the request on Step 1. So if the browser sends parameter x as encoded, your also going to have to send it encoded in Jmeter.